# Is there a workaround when ERP System library doesn't allow multiple asynchronous log in operations

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

I have created an application that sends invoices to recipients from ERP system called Comarch Optima. To print the attachment, I use the built-in functions of this system (with COM Objects). Unfortunately, it doesn't allow you to log in from two different threads. I used Quartz.net (ver 3.0.7) as a timer and created two tasks - the first every 5 minutes and the second at 12:15. Both will trigger at the same time.

I get an error saying:

`OLE database multi-step operation generated errors. Check all OLE database status values. No action was taken.`

I asked the ERP support center how to solve this problem. I've received the answer:

`It is not possible to log in several times simultaneously within one process. Such operations must be performed synchronously. If one thread logs in, another thread cannot log in, it must wait for the first thread to complete all operations and log off.`

Am I able to do anything about it? Should I change Quartz to something else?

Comment: If you're running the same job on multiple schedules, a simple fix is to add the `[DisallowConcurrentExecution]` attribute. If it's different jobs and they don't run for too long, a workaround is to make them grab a common lock (like a `SemaphoreSlim`) so they don't run at the same time. If they different jobs *and* they're long-running, you may need to get tricky with a custom scheduler. If you do not actually need concurrency at all (for any job), setting the global `quartz.threadPool.maxConcurrency = 1` (in `quartz.config`) would disable it entirely.

Comment: @JeroenMostert but I still need to run second task. `[DisallowConcurrentExecution]` doesn't make queue so if I have a task that executes only once per day it would never be executed. I should be able to run much more tasks at the same time. This is just an example.

Comment: That's only the first alternative I provided. You can run as many tasks as you please, but only one can ever use the ERP system at a time, per the feedback you received. This means that, one way or another, you have to ensure exclusive access. Wrapping the connection access in all jobs (with a static `SemaphoreSlim`, for example) is one way to do that (`maxConcurrency = 1` *does* allow tasks to run in series, by the way). If you need true concurrency even for accessing the ERP, that's up to your vendor to fix, not you.

Comment: There seems to be no solution. Each interference in the thread where ERP system objects are created gets a null reference exception. `Login()` method requires to pass `ModuleCollection` object with selected modules. I get an exception on `ModuleCollection mc = new ModuleCollection()` which doesn't make any sens... Stacktrace also ends there. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Since this is COM, you might be running into apartment issues (basically, what COM calls threading) where you are required to use COM objects only on the thread that created them, and furthermore this thread must have the correct apartment mode to be able to use those objects. If that's the case, you are best off forgetting about threading at all. Use a priority queue for scheduling things (with some `Threading.Timer`s to enter events) and run everything off a single thread. In theory, you can write a custom scheduler for this in Quartz that will do this. In practice, I doubt it's worth it.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I'm afraid I have to do this somehow. Otherwise, I will have to create document templates from scratch based on the appearance of the document from the ERP system. I don't know what's worse...